# How to express one-to-many in Django and use append and remove?

Tags: python, django, database, model

```
class Player(models.Model):
    owner =  models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True,related_name = "player_owner")
    slaves = models.ManyToManyField('self',blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to define a Player model, whose instance can have its slaves composing by other players;at the same time it could be a slave of other player.

How to define the slaves field and manipulate it in terms of an instance?

Comment: `p = Player(); p2=Player(); p.save(); p2.save(); p.slaves.add(p2); `?

Answer (score 0):

Best to refer to the docs
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)